# Naming conventions in swagger or in general generating proxy clients

Tags: java, swagger, naming-conventions

I was wondering if I had to include the word proxy when generating a proxy-api.

So which is better?
swagger generate client -i https://developing.cart.com.uy/cart/v1/swagger.json -l java -o generated-client -Djava8=true **--api-package=com.cart.proxy.api**

swagger generate client -i https://developing.cart.com.uy/cart/v1/swagger.json -l java -o generated-client -Djava8=true **--api-package=com.cart.api**

I mean, should I include the name "proxy" in the package name?